# How can I set object in list

Tags: c#, variables

I have code:

```
Foo f1 = new Foo();
Foo f2 = new Foo();

List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>() { f1 };

// ... 

Foo f = list[0];
f = f2; // <===

Console.WriteLine((list[0] == f));
```

Last line display "false". But i want change 'list[0]' by changing 'f' variable (not list[0] directly) (line '<==='). May be, i need use pointers (e.g. create new object in &list[0] address)?

Comment: _why_ do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want change `list[0]` by changing `f` variable (not `list[0]` directly)

That is not possible. The collection `list` is made up of pointers to objects as are the variables `f1`, `f2`, and `f` each a pointer to an object.

By changing the pointer of `f` you do not automatically change the pointer held in the collection that happened to be pointing to the same object.

---

*By the way, this behavior is a good thing.*